# Dynamically Adapting EDMX Definition at Runtime

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, runtime, odata

We have an EF edmx file in use to define the conceptual model of db. This is than used to access the database from our odata provider.

The problem at hand is we have found that due to the size (very large) of the edmx certain things cause the EF to really bog down in certain situations. The main hit is relationships between tables. When a relationship is added between a table there seems to be an exponential growth in latency when odata or webapi surfaces that data.

The situation is that we only use those relationships in 5% of all runtime cases.

My question is, is there a way to dynamically change the edmx at runtime to add in the relationships when we require them so in the 95% of all other cases they don't affect performance? Is this possible to change edmx definition at runtime and are there repercussions to this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change it multiple times throughout the execution or will you configure it at start up and it will remain the same for the entire execution of your application?

Comment: it could be changed multiple times at execution

Comment: There are a couple or problems here.  1) Entity Framework runs your model configuration once per App Domain.  You will probably need to find a way to clear this before making any changes.  2) It will probably need to re-run all of the configurations and rebuild all of the views.  This is very expensive.  I'm worried that this may cause more performance problems than it fixes.

Comment: Do you have the problem because the number of entities the context is tracking is big?